# RxJava chain calls that follow an Observable<Void>

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I've been wrapping a synchronous library so every method that does IO returns an `Observable`. However some of these methods return `Observable<Void>` as I'm only caring about its completion.

How do I chain calls after an `Observable` that doesn't emit anything?

```
accountManager.doAuth()
            .flatMap(x -> paginator.next())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(... subscriber stuff ...)
```

I have to call `doAuth` for every request and it returns `Observable<Void>`. Since it doesn't emit items, `onNext` is never called, only `onCompleted`.

Regarding `doAuth` I only care if it completes or gives an error. If it completes I would like that `paginator.next()` was called so I could implement my own logic in `onCompleted/onError/onNext`.

Until now I've been using `flatMap` to chain calls and it works fine when I actually care about the things that the previous Observables returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since release of `1.1.1` `RxJava` has `Completable` which perfectly fits your requirement. Instead of returning `Observable<Void>` you could return `Completable`:

```
public Completable doAuth(){
    return Completable.create(subscriber -> {
        //do auth
        if(authOk) subscriber.onCompleted();
        else subscriber.onError(throwable);
    });
}
```

Great articles about `Completable`: [part one](http://akarnokd.blogspot.ru/2015/12/the-new-completable-api-part-1.html), [part two](http://akarnokd.blogspot.ru/2015/12/the-new-completable-api-part-2-final.html)

Comment: supposed I need to perform few Completable's and then Observable and subscribe at the end, How can I do this?

Comment: @Shvalb there is `andThen()` operator in `Completeable`, which acts very like flatMap in `Observable`